# Java JComboBox can't see

Tags: java

I have problem with JComboBox, I dont see it in my window. I dont know what I am doing wrong. 
I have added coordinates of JComboBox in my code, but I cant see it after running the code.

My code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
class klasa extends JFrame
{
    public klasa()
    {   
        super("Program to obliczania wartosci logicznych");
        setSize(300, 250);
        setVisible(true);
        JButton oblicz = new JButton("Oblicz");
        oblicz.setBounds(190, 160, 80, 40);
        add(oblicz);
        String[]opcje= {"OR","AND","XOR"};
        JComboBox<String> lista = new JComboBox<>(opcje);
        lista.setBounds(150, 150, 2, 4);
        add(lista);
        //lista.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    klasa k1 = new klasa(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JCombobox is displayed, but is overlapped by a button - just resize your window and see. Looks like you should use some layout to fix this & play with element coordinates

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't set a Layout for your frame, which means by default, its using the BorderLayout. So you place the two objects on top of each other.

Other than that, try instantiating your frame on the Event Dispatch Thread. Using your code base it would look something like this:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class klasa extends JFrame {

    public JComboBoxExample() {
        super("Program to obliczania wartosci logicznych");

        this.setLayout(null);

        setSize(300, 250);
        setVisible(true);
        JButton oblicz = new JButton("Oblicz");
        oblicz.setBounds(190, 160, 80, 40);
        add(oblicz);
        String[]opcje= {"OR","AND","XOR"};
        JComboBox<String> lista = new JComboBox<>(opcje);
        lista.setBounds(150, 150, 20, 40);
        add(lista);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new klasa();
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Check out the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Place the setSize and setVisible methods after the JComboBox.

```
class klasa extends JFrame
{
    public klasa()
    {   
        super("Program to obliczania wartosci logicznych");
        //setSize(300, 250); Comment this section out
        //setVisible(true); Comment this section out
        JButton oblicz = new JButton("Oblicz");
        oblicz.setBounds(190, 160, 80, 40);
        add(oblicz);
        String[]opcje= {"OR","AND","XOR"};
        JComboBox<String> lista = new JComboBox<>(opcje);
        lista.setBounds(150, 150, 2, 4);
        add(lista);
        //lista.setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 250);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        klasa k1 = new klasa(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesent work, this is the same problem as firstly